# Can ng-model update another ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, html

This is my code:

```
<table ng-init="liveTotal={}">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in sovCtrl.topics" >
    <td> {{x}}</td>
    <td><input ng-model="sovCtrl.objects[x]" type="number"></td>
    <td ng-hide="true">
        <input ng-model="liveTotal[$index]" type="number" value="{{sovCtrl.objects[x]}}">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div > Current Result:
  {{ 0 + liveTotal[0] + liveTotal[1] + liveTotal[2] + liveTotal[3] + liveTotal[4]}} 
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is have a live result of the sum of all the Inputted topic values(there will never be more than 5) without using $scope or any extra sovCtrl methods/objects or adding a script;
The topics are strings I can't predict.

The 2nd input CHANGES when I type into the first input, but the result in the div does not. 
The result in the div changes only when I type or press on the 2nd input(if I make it visible)

Can this be done using angular but modifying only the above HTML?

Edit: sovCtrl.objects gets passed into functions that graph the values. Modifying the the keys would break those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, this works.

```
<table ng-init="liveTotal={}">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in sovCtrl.topics" >
    <td> {{x}}</td>
    <td><input ng-model="sovCtrl.objects[x]" type="number"></td>
    <td ng-show="false"> {{ liveTotal[$index]= sovCtrl.shareOfVoice[x]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div > Current Result:
 {{ 0 + liveTotal[0] + liveTotal[1] + liveTotal[2] + liveTotal[3] + liveTotal[4]}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you directly do something like shown below 
wherein you directly use the first input
You just add an index (which is provided in ng-repeat of any variable) and now you can access values by using index 0,1,2,3,4

```
<table ng-init="liveTotal={}">
    <tr ng-repeat="(i,x) in sovCtrl.topics" >
        <td> {{x}}</td>
        <td><input ng-model="sovCtrl.objects[x]" ng-change="sovCtrl.objects_yo[i]=sovCtrl.objects[x]" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div> Current Result:
    {{ 0 + sovCtrl.objects_yo[0] + sovCtrl.objects_yo[1] + sovCtrl.objects_yo[2] + sovCtrl.objects_yo[3] + sovCtrl.objects_yo[4]}}
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but "The topics are strings I can't predict"

Comment: So you want to convert the strings to numbers and add them(if they are indeed numbers), only in html?

Comment: sovCtrl.objects is something like this {name: 0, :anothername:10, lastname:20}

Comment: How about now @lonewarrior556?

Comment: Question edited, objects[i] would not pull the right value into the input area, or save it to the right object key

Comment: How about now @lonewarrior556?

Comment: I tried that, using ng-change doesn't live updating on keystroke only on blur